# Multiplying a list by a nested list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to multiply a list by a nested list.

For example if we have

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[[2,4,6],[3,5,7]]
```

I am trying to multiply each element of 'list b' by elements of 'list a'

I am trying to achieve something along these lines

```
product=[[2,8,18],[3,10,21]]
```

Here is what I tried so far

```
product=[[w*c for c in v] for w, v in zip(a, b)]
```

and result I got is

```
[[-4.0, -8.0, -12.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

which is clearly not what I expected

I am not allowed to use numpy by the way.

Comment: You have the `zip` in the wrong place - you need to `zip` `a` with the inner lists (what you're currently calling `v`), not the outer list.

Comment: `res = [[i*j for i, j in zip(subl, a)]for subl in b]` you need to see what `a` is multiplying and use that list in zip with `a`

Comment: instead of using list comprehension, i suggest you to do this using loops and then proceed with list comprehension for more understanding

Comment: Thank you guys, yes that sounds reasonable to me, if I start with loops first

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you! the problem was indeed in that I put zip in the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a inner `zip`, because a outer zip will zip with a and b, with each pairs of list with each element in a, so it will fail.

```
print([[y*z for y,z in zip(a,x)] for x in b])
```

Output:

```
[[2, 8, 18], [3, 10, 21]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[[2,4,6],[3,5,7]]

for idxa, val in enumerate(a):
    for idxb, sublist in enumerate(b):
        b[idxb][idxa] = sublist[idxa] * val
```

Results in b equal to `[[2, 8, 18], [3, 10, 21]]` and may be easier to reason about if just starting out with Python rather than dealing with list comprehension and zip or other functional programming calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` in combination with list comprehension:

```
product = [[i*j for i,j in zip(a,k)] for k in b]
```